# PacketRecords in DELPHI - How it works behind the scenes

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset

Well, I'm studying the "packetRecord" property (TClientDataSet) and i have a doubt about it. I will explain how i think this works and if i'm wrong, correct me please.

1 - If i configure th packetRecord = 50, when i do "SELECT * FROM history", if table history have 200k of rows, the TClientDataSet will do something like this: "SELECT * FROM history limit 50", so when i need more 50 rows the ClientDataSet will search more 50 in Database.

The property packetRecord just make senses if TClientDataSet don't get all rows in Database, at least for me.

Am i correct ?

Answer (score 0):

It will probably execute the entire query and ask to return just 50 records, but that is an implementation detail that I think is not chosen by the ClientDataSet but rather by the provider, the dataset or the driver.
But in general, that is more or less how it works, yes.

Did some browsing through the code. If the ClientDataSet is linked to a (local) TDataSetProvider, that provider just opens the dataset it is connected to. After opening it, it sets the DataSet.BlockReadSize property to the number of records to retrieve (=packetRecords).

So in the end it comes down on the implementation of BlockReadSize and the dsBlockRead state of the TDataSet that is used.

With a client-server setup this must be the same thing. In fact, there doesn't even have to be a dataset or even a database. There's also an TXMLTransformProvider, and people could implement custom providers too. TXMLTransformProvider ignores this value completely.

So, like I said above, there is no general rule on how this works and even *if* this properties has any effect.

Comment: Helpful information but i need something more exact, i'm doing a study about that to better the performance of a system.

Comment: Maybe your DBMS logs the queries? That might tell you whether it executes one query or indeed adds a limit.

Comment: Did some digging in the code. Like I thought, the ClientDataSet doesn't do anything with that property except passing it to the provider, which basically passes it to the dataset, if there is any. In the end it depends on the implementation of BlockReadSize and the dsBlockRead state of the TDataSet that is used. Added this info to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

see TDataPacketWriter.WriteDataSet. no matter whether underlying dataset supports block read mode or not it (datapacket writer) will stop writing data packet as soon as requested amount of records processed (or Eof state reached)